# Python: using dictionary as input with bokeh library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

**Context**

Say I have a dictionary:

`d = {‘2012': [50, 62], '2013': [53, 55], '2014': [51,52]...}`,

... where keys are years and values are lists of values (eg. `[female employees, male employees]`).

**Question**

How can a stacked bar chart (with years on x-axis) with bokeh be created using this dictionary? Or - how else could this data be used to make this possible?

Comment: by the way, what I get when I try to create a data frame like this:
df = pd.DataFrame([d], columns=d.keys())
is a plot where it says 2012 on the y axis and then there are two bars, one with 50 and one with 62

Comment: Why don't you add the plotting code you're using (if it's short), since that's where the problem seems to be occurring?

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Bokeh, use `vbar_stack`:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
colors = ["#c9d9d3", "#718dbf", "#e84d60"]

data = {'fruits' : fruits,
        '2015'   : [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4],
        '2016'   : [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6],
        '2017'   : [3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 3]}

p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, title="Fruit Counts by Year",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar_stack(years, x='fruits', width=0.9, color=colors, source=data`,
             legend=[value(x) for x in years])

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None
p.legend.location = "top_left"
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"

show(p)
```

[image]